# insert new record in secondary table without insert in main table in hibernate(one entity , two table)

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations

I have one entity in hibernate  called country, but want to mapped it into two tables  for some reason
here is my country class  and its ER-diagram

[country and country lang ER diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26PXG.jpg)

[country class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9JGv.jpg)

but as you see this entity has one uniqueConstraints  on countryCode

this constrain caused to when I wanna add  an entity with two names( in different languages)  for example :

name---countryCode----languageId

US------1------------en

America....1........fa

I catched exception

now 
my question is :
how to insert  new record into secondary table without insert new  related record into main table

note: these two record may be sent in different request by client

Comment: Your domain model simply won't work with that unique constraint as you have shown with how you want to model your data.  You either need to eliminate the constraint are redesign the data model.  Can you elaborate a tad on what name/countryCode/languageId are representing?  Is it something like en_US tied to country code 001?

Comment: I ask this question because I thought  there is a solution( like as some annotation in hibernate ) that can help me to do it  ........ but it seems i should redesign my data model  and combine two table (country and country_lang) to one table  with a bit redundancy

Comment: Why would you combine two tables? You want to have one country with multiple names (in different languages). Just create a list of country_lang objects within a country and map properly, using OneToMany/ManyToMany.

Comment: yes it is possible when user create country object with some language list in one request at one time . but in my web app scenario , user may send different country object creation request any time ,, please see this link ......http://img.majidonline.com/pic/318161/ffff.jpg ...this is my web app scenario